# Find out whether the ougoing call is to a phone call or a data request

Tags: android, phone-number

I'm developing an Android app that receives the ougoing call event and extract the destination address from it, cancel the call for doing some process and then redial the same address number automatically without user intention.

The problem: I don't want to process destination numbers which are not a real destination phone address (i.e. a USSD number like *21# which make some data request on some operator). **How can I find out dinamically (without maintaining any table) whether the outgoing destination is a phone call or a data request from the operator?**

Comment: Chances are that if it has an asterisk or pound sign, then it is not a phone number. And I believe all the USSD codes do have either a pound sign or an asterisk.

Comment: but a real call number could contain asterisk also - a short numbers like *4444.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to check if the number matches the format of a USSD:

> A typical USSD message starts with a * followed by digits which
>   indicate an action to be performed or are parameters. Each group of
>   numbers is separated by a *, and the message is terminated with a #.

USSDs have a maximum length of 182 characters.

Comment: hmm yea.. that is a typical USSD request format. I'll clarify my problem: I don't want to tell whether the number is USSD or not but to tell whether the number is a real phone number that will actually cause a voice call - I want to distinguish between that dial type and the rest, if it's in the rest, I don't wanna know if it was a USSD or some dialing mistake...

Comment: So to clarify, are you talking about only GSM calls? Not calls placed over VoIP or Skype?